# Search contact by EmailAddress EWS

Tags: soap, exchangewebservices

I want to search contact by EmailAddress. Use for it following code

```
<m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
  <m:ItemShape>
    <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
    <t:AdditionalProperties>
      <t:FieldURI FieldURI="contacts:DisplayName" />
    </t:AdditionalProperties>
  </m:ItemShape>
  <m:Restriction>
  <t:Or>

    <t:Contains ContainmentMode="Substring" ContainmentComparison="IgnoreCase">
      <t:IndexedFieldURI FieldURI="contacts:EmailAddress" FieldIndex="EmailAddress1" />
        <t:Constant Value="test" />
    </t:Contains>

    <t:Contains ContainmentMode="Substring" ContainmentComparison="IgnoreCase">
      <t:IndexedFieldURI FieldURI="contacts:EmailAddress" FieldIndex="EmailAddress2" />
        <t:Constant Value="test" />
    </t:Contains>

    <t:Contains ContainmentMode="Substring" ContainmentComparison="IgnoreCase">
      <t:IndexedFieldURI FieldURI="contacts:EmailAddress" FieldIndex="EmailAddress3" />
        <t:Constant Value="test" />
    </t:Contains> 
  </t:Or>

</m:Restriction>
    <m:ParentFolderIds>
    <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="contacts" />
  </m:ParentFolderIds>
</m:FindItem>
```

And it works fine for some contacts. But, how should I search, if value of some contact email address is

```
  <t:EmailAddresses>
  <t:Entry Key="EmailAddress1">/o=Server/ou=Exchange Administrative Group/cn=Recipients/cn=Testdeb</t:Entry>
  <t:Entry Key="EmailAddress2">secondtest@email.com</t:Entry>
  </t:EmailAddresses>
```

instead of simple string (EmailAddress1 vs EmailAddress2)
And I do not know, how to make search on EmailAddress1 value from that location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to using FindItems you can use the ResolveName operation to search just the contacts folder (as opposed to the directory) if you have the EmailAddress it will handle searching across all those properties and return entries that match. eg

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="
http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://sc
hemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xml
soap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:ResolveNames ReturnFullContactData="true" SearchScope="Contacts">
      <m:UnresolvedEntry>frt@me.com</m:UnresolvedEntry>
    </m:ResolveNames>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

You can then bind to the contacts based on EWSId returned in the Mailbox element

Cheers
Glen